# I know there are websites which can help me find a cuddle friend. But is there any Android app which can help?

Tags: android, social-networks, search, recommendation-engine

## A note on safety

If you want to meet a cuddle friend using any website or app — first, please read
["How to Be Safe While Meeting People Online"](http://cuddlebids.com/safe-meeting-people-online/).

## My question

If I want to find a new [cuddle friend](http://web.archive.org/web/http://www.lovecoaching.com/cuddle-buddy-and-bonk-buddy-guidelines/) ("cuddle buddy"), there are various websites that can help me.  For example:

- I can use the [Cuddle Comfort](http://www.cuddlecomfort.com/) website.  (I've already successfully found one cuddle friend through this website in the past.)
- Or I can search my local Craigslist "strictly platonic" personals for something like `cuddl* | touch* | massag*`.
- Some asexuals don't like touch, but some do.  If I want to cuddle with one of the latter, I can sign up for [Acebook](http://www.ace-book.net/).

But which apps can help me?

The iPhone/iPad app [CuddleBids](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cuddlebids/id931581979?mt=8) looks like it could let me find a cuddle friend; but I don't own an iOS device.  The founder of CuddleBids [claims](http://www.quora.com/When-will-CuddleBids-be-available-for-Android) that an Android port will be available this year; however, it's not yet available.

Traditionally, another option has been the Cuddlr app (Android / iOS).  From their website, it sounds like they've written a location-based social-discovery app for cuddling — in other words, an app that lets you view the profiles of people near you and that lets you send them "cuddle requests".

But Cuddlr is no longer available.  They ran into [various problems](https://medium.com/@charliewilliams/one-last-hug-ff07648f1900) and ended up shutting down their servers.

What apps are *presently* available which can are specifically designed to help me find a cuddle friend, on a platform which I have access to?

## My requirements, in order of importance

1. Most importantly, I'm looking for a smartphone app which can help me find a cuddle friend.
2. It must not be exclusive to iOS.  It's best if it works on Android or Windows 10.  (If it requires another platform such as BlackBerry OS, please do let me know; but it'd be best if you'd post your find as a comment, not an answer.  Maybe I can install an emulator on my PC.)
3. It's best if it's gratis.  (Ad-supported is fine.)
4. It'd be nice if I could filter the search results so that individuals closer to me would be listed first.  Because I don't live in the US, this means that the app must either:

   - Allow me to specify my approximate location by tapping a point on a map.
   - Or capture my coarse location, using cellphone tower triangulation.
   - Or understand the postal code systems in the English-speaking countries outside the US.

Comment: Sorry but this sounds off-topic in view of this: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2627/is-requesting-a-service-that-has-a-software-part-on-topic . This policy is indeed posterious to your question, but nonetheless applicable.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: "Posterious". Interesting word! An older Scottish word meaning "subsequent". ... Anyway. Paid cuddling requires a purchase of services; free cuddling doesn't. It would be excellent if you could please let this question stand. Maybe because free cuddling matchmaking services are a real thing. Or maybe my question could be "grandfathered in" because it's older than the policy.